# Is it possible to get inertial rotation on pan for a node without using ’allowsCameraControl’ in SceneKit?

Tags: swift, xcode, rotation, scenekit

My goal is to build a scene with a floating or ‘zero g’ node fixed to the center of the screen that can be spun around freely on pan but without SceneKit camera controls.

With `allowsCameraControl` enabled, the rotation is perfectly smooth and the inertia works great but the rotation is backwards at times since the entire camera is moving around.

Is it possible to get the same inertial rotation as camera control with a custom pan gesture for a single node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AllowsCameraControl is very limited.  You "might" be able to code enough of a pan gesture to get around it, but try the post below - it's a 10 minute deal to add a Camera class and you'll have a lot more flexibility.  Pan gesture will be easier too.

55129224 - this post gives you quick example of creating a camera class. You can use this to reposition your camera or move it forward and back, etc.

Hope that helps.